# Not able to install pygame module in windows

Tags: python-2.7, pip, pygame

I am trying to install pygame using pip install pygame but it does not work...

```
C:\Python27\pygame-1.9.1release>pip install pygame  
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried to run the setup.py file from pygame-1.9.1release but i got the following traceback...

```
No Arguments Given, Perform Default Install? [Y/n]y
WARNING, DLL for smpeg library not found.
WARNING, DLL for tiff library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL_ttf library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL_image library not found.
WARNING, DLL for vorbisfile library not found.
WARNING, DLL for jpeg library not found.
WARNING, DLL for vorbis library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL_mixer library not found.
WARNING, DLL for png library not found.
WARNING, DLL for SDL library not found.
WARNING, DLL for ogg library not found.
WARNING, DLL for z library not found.
WARNING, DLL for portmidi library not found.
running install
running build
running build_py 
running build_ext
building 'pygame._numericsurfarray' extension

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\pygame-1.9.1release\setup.py", line 491, in <module>
setup(**PACKAGEDATA)
File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
raise SystemExit, "error: " + str(msg)
SystemExit: error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Please guide me how can i use pip command...and how can i install pygame

i am using python2.7.8

While trying to do get-pip.py in python2.7.8 python shell i am getting the following traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hardik\Downloads\get-pip(3).py", line 20204, in <module> main()  
File "C:\Users\hardik\Downloads\get-pip(3).py", line 152, in main bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)  
File "C:\Users\hardik\Downloads\get-pip(3).py", line 130, in bootstrap sys.exit(pip.main(["install", "--upgrade"] + packages + args))  
File "c:\users\hardik\appdata\local\temp\tmpj_gcu3\pip.zip\pip\__init__.py", line 217, in main  
File "c:\users\hardik\appdata\local\temp\tmpj_gcu3\pip.zip\pip\basecommand.py", line 183, in main  
File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 776, in dictConfig dictConfigClass(config).configure()  
File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\config.py", line 575, in configure '%r: %s' % (name, e))  
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': closed
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install pip on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: I have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows...this...but i am not able to run get-pip.py file...don't know where is the mistake...in command prompt following thing is displayed...  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection
failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
  No distributions at all found for pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to install `pip`, [try using this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) to help.

Download the file `get_pip.py` and then run it, then you will succesfully have installed `pip`.

Alternatively, look at [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) for more help.

Comment: I have tried that...i am getting error...  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connec
tion broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection
failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
  No distributions at all found for pip

Comment: Thanks for your answer...it helped...successfully installed pip and pygame

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that

```
c:\python27\scripts
```

Is in your *PATH* environment variable.